# Read images from Photo Stream on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, iphoto, photostream

it's quite easy and normal to use images from Photo Stream with iPhone. I wonder if there's anyway to read images from Photo Stream on OS X?

After some googling, I found out the images are actually synced in `~/Library/Application Support/iLifeAssetManagement/assets`, do I have to parse the files here?

Big thanks!